# Batch command to copy latest directories from ftp server to local machine

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, ftp

I have builds coming up on an ftp server on each day. I want to write a batch file which schedules the copy of the latest build directory to the local folder. I have tried creating a batch file using the command

```
ftp -s:ftp.txt
```

the ftp.txt contains the following:

```
open server_address
username
Passwordcd InDesign
cd \\path to the directory where builds are posted
get *
```

It shows an error 550 file cannot be opened.
But when I mention the name of the file i.e.

```
get filename
```

It downloads the file I don't know where.
After I will be able to resolve this file copying I want to get the latest directory copied to my local folder. I have tried all the methods from online investigation but none of them are working. I want to implement this without using any ftp servers except the windows ftp.exe. I have tried wget as well but it shows invalid command. And at the end I want to use windows scheduler to schedule all this at a particular time of the day.

Comment: I dont want to use any external ftp client, in that suggested question it asks to use WinSCP FTP client .

Comment: As mentioned in my answer there, you can hardly do what you ask for using the `ftp`.

Comment: There has to be a way with ftp as well. I want to ask for that.

Comment: Does the folder you want to download have subdirectories?

Comment: Yes it contains a logs directory and a zip file.

Comment: If it has a fixed structure like this, then you may create a local `log` folder explicitly, download the separately the zip file, and separately download all files from the remote `log` folder. If the structure ever changes, your script breaks - Again the `ftp` does not support recursive transfers.

Comment: Can you please suggest how should i go with the ftp.txt file if the folder structure is same and I need the latest folder's contents.
Like the latest folder is 432 and it has logs folder which has some .txt files and a zip file .zip. then again next day , I will have 433 folder name and the same content. How should I go

Comment: timestamp of the folder created or the last 24 hr created folder.

Comment: Selecting by timestamp is insane task using the `ftp`. Can you select the folder name alphabetically? I.e. do the folders < 100 have 0 prepended or not - Is there `099` or `99`?

Comment: Anyway, you have two question here. Selecting the latest folder and downloading a folder with fixed structure. Ask them separately. Edit your current question to ask for one of these.

Comment: Folder names go like this 989353 ... 989360 and so on , we can select for a greater value than the current as well or the last folder added in the past 24 hrs.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Can you select the latest folder alphabetically?

Comment: No we cant select latest folder alphabetically !

Comment: OK, I suggest you pick your question.